# Querying data from Elasticsearch

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elk, kibana-7

Using Elasticsearch 7.*, trying to execute SQL query on an index 'com-prod':

```
GET /com-prod/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "test1": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "params._source.ElapsedTime"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It gives the output and below as one of the hit successfully:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "com-prod",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "abcd",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "test1" : [
            "29958"
          ]
        }
      }
```

Now, I am trying to increment the ElapsedTime by 2, as below:

```
GET /com-prod/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "test2": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "params._source.ElapsedTime + 2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But its actually adding number 2 to the output, as below:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "com-prod",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "abcd",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "test2" : [
            "299582"
          ]
        }
      }
```

Please guide what could be wrong here, and how to get the output as 29960.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are getting `299582`, instead of `29960`, because the `ElapsedTime` field is of string type ("29958")**, so when you are adding `2` in this using script, `2` gets appended at the end (similar to concat two strings).

So, in order to solve this issue, you can :

1. Create a new index, with updated mapping of the `ElaspsedTIme` field of `int` type, then reindex the data. Then you can use the same search query as given in the question above.
2. Convert the `string` to an `int` type value, using `Integer.parseInt()`

```
GET /com-prod/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "test2": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "Integer.parseInt(params._source.ElapsedTime) + 2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```